# how to create video by images using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, ffmpeg

I have some images video12.jpeg,video13.jpeg,video14.jpeg,video15.jpeg and I want to covert images to video. 
Please check below code but but it not working...

first try by...

```
exec("ffmpeg -i movie.mpg -r 0.2 -sameq -f image2 video%02d.jpeg");// not create video if put video%02d.jpg instead of video%02d.jpeg
```

secode try

```
exec('ffmpeg -r 10 -b 1800 -i video%03d.jpeg test1800.mp4');//// not create video if put video%02d.jpg instead of video%02d.jpeg
```

Please suggest me how to create video using images.

Comment: Please explain how it is not working, which result do you see?

Comment: I dont know but there is not get any output.

Comment: I have just created index.php file write code and put these images in same folder.

Comment: Did you test the `ffmpeg` commands, manually and unscripted in cli, first before attempting to use them in a script? Is the issue with your script, with the ffmpeg commands, and/or something else? You need to narrow it down.